# Mac Eclipse GCC 4.9.0 "The program file specified in the launch configuration does not exist"

Tags: c++, eclipse, macos, gcc

I'm on eclipse on a mac and I just set the settings in my "working" project telling Eclipse to use my GCC 4.9.0 instead of the 4.2.1 but when I run my program which is just a version-test.cpp (I'm following Bill Weinman's videos and I've done every step he did on the video) it says

"The program file specified in the launch configuration does not exist. The file /Users/Tanner/Documents/workspace/Working/Debug/Working does not exist"

But I know that before I changed the settings, that "working" executable in the debug folder did exist. Somehow it vanished or went someplace else after I changed my settings and tried to run the version-test.cpp again. But in Weinman's video his worked and switched to the later GCC version. I'm not experienced at all with this stuff I am just a beginner, having trouble trying to solve this problem. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go into the properties of the Working folder (if you are following the lynda.com program you will understand the working folder) and under C/C++ Build -> Environment menu (Where we added in the LIBRARY_PATH, PATH, AND CPATH) variables and add in DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH with a value of ${HOME}/hpc-gcc/lib.

Remember the C/C++ Build "menus" are for build and debug, so the project is not able to find the library for the building process.

And you will be good to go.